# PIC understanding the sign of the integer that is in the register

Tags: pic, c

I am getting current data from CANBus, they send me the value as a signed number. The problem is even if the number is supposed to be negative `if(current<0)` is always `true` and it never becomes `if(current<0)`. So I think that I cannot check the sign of the number in the register like that. So is there way to check if the number is positive or negative?
I declared current as an integer number and I directly put register value in it like that:

```
int current;
current = RXB0D0;
if(current>0){
    led1=1;}
if(current<0){
    led2=1;}
```

Edit: This is the battery spec I am following : [datasheet](http://sbs-forum.org/specs/sbdat110.pdf)

On page 59 current() section.

Comment: It all depends how `RXB0D0` is defined. If it is defined as an **un**signed char, for example, `current` can never be negative.

Comment: That is the register which is (1 sec I will show)

Comment: Yes, but **how is it defined**? As signed or unsigned value?  (you probably have to look in a *.h-file)?

Comment: I am not sure how it is defined, I do not have *.h file I use Micro C

Comment: There is this information: First byte is LSB and second byte is MSB and I check only the first byte. Do I also need to check the second byte?

Comment: There must be somewhere a h-file, that contains the definition of `RXB0D0`. Maybe in a folder named "includes", "inc", "headers" etc.

Comment: So RXB0D0 means first byte which is LSB. I can also check RXB0D1 which is MSB. Does it help me with finding the sign?

Comment: If it is the MSByte, it is enough to check that one. It works, however, only if it is signed. You can, however, do an explicit type cast: `(signed char)`or `(int8_t)`. Then it doesn't matter what type is used for definition.

Comment: I don't know about the endianess of that controller (i.e. which of the two is the MSB/LSB). In any case you have to use the **M**SByte. It is enough to test the MSByte if you are only interested in the sign.

Comment: If the number is 2's complement format, it's negative if the most significant **bit** of the most significant **byte** is 1. You could just test that, but it would be ugly and bad for maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `RXB0D0` and `RXB0D1` are defined as `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

It should work as expected if you do an explicit type cast of the **M**SByte to a **signed** byte type:

`current = (int8_t)RXB0D1;`

or

`current = (signed char)RXB0D1;`

You even don't need to use a separate variable. You could also do
`if ((int8_t)RXB0D1 < 0) {...}`

Comment: I believe current = (signed char)RXB0D0; made it zero. and int8_t gives me errors that is not suppoerted in Micro C I believe

Comment: No, `current = (signed char)RXB0D0;`definitely does not make it Zero if it was a non-zero byte value before; and in order to use `int8_t`, you have to include `stdint.h` or `inttypes.h`.

Comment: Okay I will try again and inform you thanks

Comment: Okay now when I use current = (signed char)RXB0D0; this time current can be negative but this time it cannot be positive I believe :/ . I know it does not sound logical but.

Comment: Didn't you say above that RXB0D0 is LSB? Then of course you should use RXB0D1. You must use the **M**SByte.

Comment: Okay so from my trials if I use   current = (signed char)RXB0D1;  current is always 0

Comment: if I use  current = RXB0D0, then current is always positive

Comment: If I use current = 1RXB0D1 then current is again zero or positive

Comment: is it because current is an int variable?

Comment: You must use `current = (signed char)RXB0D1;`or `current = (int8_t)RXB0D1;` (both work equally well).

Comment: BTW: maybe your original value is actually always zero or positive?

Comment: I do not believe that is always zero or positive. And also when I use current= (signed char)RXB0D0; it was giving me negative values

Comment: "is it because current is an int variable?" NO! It is because  RXB0D0/ RXB0D1 is defined as an **un**signed type. Please read the answer.

Comment: I tried the uint_8 method too that does not work either. When I try with current = (int8_t)RXB0D1; that is always zero and

Comment: When I try with current = (int8_t)RXB0D0; only positive and zero

Answer (score 1):

I guess RXB0D0 is defined as an uint8_t or similar, so it can't be negative.

You can probably trick the compiler to interpret it as signed:

```
current = * (int8_t*) & RXB0D0;
```

Another option is a DIY conversion:

```
int16_t current = RXB0D0;
if( current > 127 ){ current -= 256 )
```

Comment: int16_t  or int8_t gives error in Micro C

Comment: @GünkutAğabeyoğlu `#include <stdint.h>` <-- that's the header where those types should be defined

Comment: Are all the `*`/`&` necessary?  This seems to be dereferencing the contents of a pointer formed from the address of a variable.  Wouldn't `(int8_t) RXB0D0` work exactly the same?

Comment: @David That would convert an out-of-bounds value, which (AFAIK) is at best implementation-defined behaviour. What I do is sort-of re-interpreting the bits that are there as signed. (I know that is not fully defined behaviour either, but most likely it is what the atmel header does anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems here.

- Data from this part is apparently stored in RXB0D0 to RXB0D7. So first of all, you need to check if you received the correct identifier and the correct size (DLC).
- You need to know the format of the data. "Value as a signed number" says nothing, you need to know the size and network endianess. CPU endianess on PIC is typically little endian but network endianess on CAN is typically big endian.
- The document you posted appears to be some API, not a protocol specification.
- You shouldn't use `int` in embedded systems (or arguably anywhere), instead use `stdint.h` types.